# add custom add to cart button in opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I need to add page to opencart.user can select one or two from product list and add to cart from this page.I can create script to collect total price and selected products. But how can I add this product and add to cart?can you give me any idea.

Comment: Clearify more pelase.

Comment: Its a electronic cigarette sale website. Customer can find,add to cart product. So I have another page.in here,customer can select parts of e cigarette. He can select any part and he can ignore any part if he don't need to buy that part.then after finished,he can see he selected parts and total price for selected parts.

Comment: this already done.Now I need add to cart button to selected parts

Comment: check product.tpl. You will get an idea from there.

Comment: Thank you.I'll try

Comment: No problem. Best of luck.